# How to get the Shared Library lists when check JVM core dump with Serviceability Agent?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, gdb, coredump

When debugging transported Core Files for the JVM with Serviceability Agent we know  Debuggers may face problems
due to the mismatch of the following two types of libraries:shared libraries and system libraries and the solution is copying all the libraries used by the program from the core host to the debugger host.

My question is how to find which libraries we need to copy? 
We saw from a book there are two ways:
one is "The list of required library files can be obtained either from the hs_err log file under the section “Dynamic Libraries”  another is " by using the native debuggers such as gdb, dbx, and WinDbg." 
However if there is no hs_err log file, however to get the required libraries by dbg? There is a command for the gdb can list them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `info sharedlibrary` or `info proc mapping` gdb command.

```
$ gdb -core core.3539 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java

(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007f5f11569a70  0x00007f5f11576ab1  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
0x00007f5f11350310  0x00007f5f1135d598  Yes (*)     /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
0x00007f5f1114ada0  0x00007f5f1114b98e  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
0x00007f5f10da08b0  0x00007f5f10ef3334  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x00007f5f11781ac0  0x00007f5f1179f640  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007f5f0ffaf840  0x00007f5f10885f58  Yes (*)     /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
0x00007f5f0fa8d600  0x00007f5f0fafed0a  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x00007f5f0f882100  0x00007f5f0f8851df  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
0x00007f5f0f6752a0  0x00007f5f0f67c2a8  Yes (*)     /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
0x00007f5f0f4525e0  0x00007f5f0f468a88  Yes (*)     /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
0x00007f5f0f23d2d0  0x00007f5f0f242bf1  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2
0x00007f5f0f026ff0  0x00007f5f0f0341e1  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
0x00007f5f0ee190b0  0x00007f5f0ee1f8ce  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2
0x00007f5f0ec071b0  0x00007f5f0ec0d2a1  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
0x00007f5f0e9ec7f0  0x00007f5f0e9fd7a8  Yes (*)     /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
0x00007f5ef2822a10  0x00007f5ef2830c68  Yes (*)     /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response , and I would mark the answer when I come back to my office after my Spring Festival vacation, as I forget the password for that account Jacky which I save the pws automatically with another PC. Happy new year to you:-)